# webpack-dev-server lazy modules loaded from wrong url

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I do have a server-side rendered (Java) application that I want to integrate with webpack-dev-server for quick development turnaround.

My java application runs on port `8080`.

I am using the following script to start a webpack-dev-server listening on `31337`.

```js
"use strict";
const webpack = require("webpack");
const WebpackDevServer = require("webpack-dev-server");

function startServer() {
    const configFactory = require("../config/webpack.config");
    const config = configFactory("development");
    const compiler = webpack(config);

    const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
        port: 31337,
        public: "localhost:31337",
    });
    devServer.listen(31337);
}

startServer();
```

In my server-side app i changed all the script tags to `src=http://localhost:31337/<bundle>`. This works fine for the main and runtime module.

But the app happens to use a design-system build with stenciljs.
When importing stencil it seems to make heavy use of lazy modules / lazy importing / code splitting. Those chunks are added to the `head` of the document as `script` tags after the initial page load.

The issue is, those generated script tags do not use `localhost:31337` as host, they are using relative paths instead (no protocol/host/port).

Is there a way to fix this? I already tried to use the `LimitChunkCountPlugin` but this does generate a runtime error when loading the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Resulting HTML:

```html
<base href="/" />
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="http://localhost:31337/js/runtime.js"
></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:31337/js/main.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/11.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/22.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/16.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/1.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/5.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/21.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/2.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/18.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/13.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/15.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/8.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/24.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this seems to be setting `output.publicPath` to a fully qualified URL.

I did change my script to the following and this seems to do the job:

```js
"use strict";
const webpack = require("webpack");
const WebpackDevServer = require("webpack-dev-server");

function startServer() {
    const configFactory = require("../config/webpack.config");
    const config = configFactory("development");
    config.output.publicPath = "http://localhost:31337/";
    const compiler = webpack(config);

    const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
        port: 31337,
        public: "localhost:31337",
        publicPath: "http://localhost:31337/",
    });
    devServer.listen(31337);
}

startServer();
```